# Count number of occurrences in 4-yr ranges

Tags: excel, ms-access, statistics, range, formula

I have a list of books and their publication dates. I want to know how many dates are in 4-year ranges.

For example, I have 5 dates as 1998, 4 in 1999, 9 in 2000, and 2 in 2001. So in the range from 1998-2000, I have 20 books.

I want to do that for 4-yr ranges back to 1800.

How can I do without physically entering the formulas in each cell. I tried to do it in excel with COUNTIF formula but I don't know how do it without entering the formula in each cell. The publication dates are in column `D` and rows `2-161`. I listed the years 1800-2018 in column `H` so my formula is `=COUNTIF(D2:D161,H2)`.  That returns the correct number, but how do I quickly calculate the other years without typing a new formula in each cell? I tried dragging the + in the corner of the cell, but that changes the range in column `D`. I want to keep the range (column `D`) constant, but change the year in each row so the formula should be

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D161, H3)
=COUNTIF(D2:D161, H4)
=COUNTIF(D2:D161, H5)
=COUNTIF(D2:D161, H6)
etc.
```

But that doesn't actually group them into 4-yr ranges. Maybe there is another way to find that information quickly with another method, formula, program, etc.

I don't know how to write code so if that is the way it needs done, please be specific on how to do it. Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-DFEC08CD-AE65-4F56-839E-5F0D8D0BACA9)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the way to avoid retyping formulas is judicious use of relative and absolute references:

To get a four year range and assuming the years are listed chronologically in column `H`, you'll need to add the sum for four consecutive rows to get a four year span

Assuming your formulas are in column `I`, starting on row `6`, use:

```
=COUNTIF(D$2:D$161, H3)+ COUNTIF(D$2:D$161, H4) + COUNTIF(D$2:D$161, H5) + COUNTIF(D$2:D$161, H6)
```

And populate down